# Firebase authefication in single-page app after refresh page

Tags: firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication

here I got some kind of problem. I'm making a vue single-page chat application with the firebase auth. Everything works fine despite the fact that every time you refresh the page you have to log in again. What do I do with my app to prevent this? I tried to search for the answer and watched some tutorials but haven't found anything close enough to my case.

Here's is my code.

Template part for login/chat blocks (I won't show you the sign up part because not sure if you really need it)

```
 <div id="login__block" v-if="state.username == ''" className="m-[10%] mt-[20%] ">
     <div class="main-block flex border-black border-2 border-l-4 border-b-4  ">
         <div className="border-r border-r-black border-r-2 py-[30px] px-[10%] w-[50%]">
             <h1 className="text-[#19B] text-[12px] lg:text-[24px]">Hey there!</h1>
              <h2 class="text-[12px] lg:text-[24px]">Yeah, you. Are you ready for a good time, kid?</h2>
          </div>
          <form @submit.prevent="Login" className="flex flex-col sm:flex-row sm:items-center sm:gap-[10%] w-[50%]  sm:w-[100%] pb-[0px] sm:py-[7%] md:py-[3%]  sm:px-[10%]" >
              <input className="border border-black w-[60%] sm:w-[50%] m-auto my-[10%] sm:m-0 sm:w-[45%] h-[50px]  lg:text-[24px]" type="email" v-model="email" placeholder="email">
              <input className="border border-black w-[60%] sm:w-[50%] m-auto my-[10%] sm:m-0 sm:w-[45%] h-[50px]  lg:text-[24px]" type="password" v-model="password"  placeholder="password">
               <input @click="Login" className="text-[15px] text-white bg-[#000]  w-[100%] sm:w-[45%] h-[50%] sm:h-[50px] font-[400] lg:text-[24px]" type="submit" value="Let's go ;]">
          </form>
    </div>
    <button @click="state.signing=true" className="w-[50%] sm:w-[20%] ml-[50%] mt-[10px] sm:ml-[80%] h-[60px] text-[11px] sm:text-[14px] md:text-[18px] lg:text-[24px] text-white bg-yellow-500 border-black border-r-2 border-l-4 border-b-4 font-[400] rounded-xl">Not with us yet?</button>
</div>






<div id="chat__block" v-else className="m-[50px] flex flex-col gap-[15px]">
    <div class="chat-header flex items-center">
        <h1 class=" w-[50%] sm:w-[80%] text-[14px] sm:text-[24px]">Happy chatting, {{ state.username }}!</h1>
         <button @click="Logout" className="w-[50%] sm:w-[20%] h-[60px] text-[11px] sm:text-[14px] md:text-[18px] lg:text-[24px] text-white bg-[#000] font-[400]">Log out</button>
     </div>
      <section class="chatbox border border-green-400 border-2 border-l-4 border-b-4 rounded-xl">
           <div v-for="message in state.messages" :bind="message.key">
                <div class="message-inner border border-yellow-300 bg-yellow-100 ">
                     <div class="text-[18px]">{{ message.content }}</div>
                      <div class="text-blue-500 text-[14px] font-[900]">{{ message.username }}</div>
                </div>
           </div>
       </section>
        <footer>
            <form @submit.prevent="SendMessage" class="flex gap-[10px]">
                <input class="border border-red-500 h-[50px] w-[50%] md:w-[300px]" type="text" v-model="inputMessage">
                <input class="border border-red-500 h-[50px] w-[50%] md:w-[100px]" type="submit" value="Send">
            </form>
        </footer>
    </div>
```

The main idea was to show the chat block when the ***state.username*** is not empty, so every time you log in the state is changed and you see the chat block instead of login form. Not sure if it will allow to realize what I want to see here but then maybe there is a better way to do that. Also, you might see, that I need to get the ***username***, not just the fact the user is logged in. That is the reason using storages is not for this case - the user can just change the data from storage and, of course, we don't want this.

And the script part

```
export default {
    setup() {
        const username = ref("")
        const email = ref("");
        const password = ref("")
        const inputUsername = ref("");
        const inputMessage = ref("");

        const auth = getAuth(app)

        const state = reactive({
            username: '',
            messages: [],
            signing: false,
        })



        const Register = () => {
            const fsref = getFirestore()
            //const user = auth.currentUser
            createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email.value, password.value)
            .then((e) => {
                updateProfile(auth.currentUser, {
                    displayName: username.value
               })
               
            }
            )
            .catch((error) => {
                const errorCode = error.code;
                const errorMessage = error.message;
                // ..
            });
            
        }

        const Login = () => {
                setPersistence(auth, browserLocalPersistence).then(() => {
                    signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email.value, password.value)
                .then(() => {
                    state.username = auth.currentUser.displayName
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    const errorCode = error.code;
                    const errorMessage = error.message;
                })
                })
                ;
                

                
            console.log('Well done')
        }

        const Logout = () => {
            state.username = '';
         }


        const SendMessage = () => {
            if(inputMessage.value == '') {
                return
            }
            const message = {
                username: state.username,
                content: inputMessage.value,
            }

            const messagesListRef = dbref(db, 'messages');
            const newMessageRef = dbpush(messagesListRef);
            set(newMessageRef, message)
            inputMessage.value = '';
        }

       

        onMounted(() => {
  

            const messagesListRef = dbref(db, 'messages');
            onValue(messagesListRef, (snapshot) => {
                const data = snapshot.val()
                let messages = [];

                Object.keys(data).forEach(key => {
                    messages.push({id: key, username: data[key].username, content: data[key].content})
                });
                state.messages = messages;

             

            })
        })


        
        return {
            state,
            inputUsername,
            inputMessage,
            username, 
            email,
            password,
            Login,
            Logout,
            Register,
            SendMessage
        }
      
    },
}
</script>
```